# data-bind with and form submit not firing

Tags: knockout.js

I have a scenario where I have a div bound to an observable using with

```
div data-bind=with:foo
```

inside this div I have form

I'm using jquery validate and so in my js I have call such as

```
$(form).validate({submitHandler...
```

The submitHandler does not work while using 'with' - if I remove the 'with' statement, the form works.

Anyone encounter this or know of a fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `with: foo` is the equivalent of doing `template: { if: foo, data: foo }`.

When you are using an anonymous template (not named, uses children), then the first thing that the binding does is save off the children of the element as a clean template and then generates the content using that "template".

So, you are likely adding your handlers to the elements prior to them being saved off as a template.

If you want to work with the actual elements that have been generated by the `with` binding, then you could choose to use the `afterRender` function.  In this case, you would specify your binding like: `data-bind="with: { data: foo, afterRender: myFunction }`.

Here are some docs on using `afterRender`: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note_3_using_afterrender_afteradd_and_beforeremove

The `afterRender` function passes in an array of elements.  You can call your wireup code at that point.